# <p:lineChart> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: lineChart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, linechart

i want to create a linechart using primefaces 5.1. but i got error message " ***Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: lineChart*** " when loading my xhtml page. this is my code

### sample.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>

 <p>LineChart is created By Manaf.</p>
    <p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{chartBean.linearModel}" legendPosition="e"          title="Linear Chart" minY="0" maxY="10" style="height:300px;"/>
    <p:lineChart id="category" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="e"title="Category Chart" minY="0" maxY="200" tyle="height:300px;margin-top:20px"/>

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

...  what is the actual problem, iam a beginner in primefaces and jsf...

Answer (score 4):

The current syntax (5.1) is ...

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" style="height:300px;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you use latest version currently it 5.1. Visit [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/downloads) or check
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of primefaces 6.2:

https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf

```
 <p:chart type="line" model="#{bean.model}" />
```

These are the different types that exist, and also each one can be customized or combined several

[image]

Comment: How is this related to the question in a way that is not already answered in other answers?

Comment: the concrete example is shown in this case in addition to all the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I'm migrating an application from PrimeFaces 6 to 13 and got a similar error, but the other way around:

```
<p:chart> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: chart
```

PrimeFaces 13 uses separate tags for each type of chart instead of a type attribute. My old syntax (PrimeFaces 6) was

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartView.model}"/>
```

This works in PrimeFaces 13:

```
<p:barChart model="#{chartView.model}"/>
```

Comment: One should always follow the [migration guide](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/../migrationguide/13_0_0). Charts uses a different third party library to render the charts than the legacy Chart component. Also, the model is different. So you cannot simply change the component.

Comment: That's very true. I first rewrote my application's Java code to fit the new model. Then I got to work on the frontend and noticed that I need to change the tag as well.